# How to get id of an object from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get id of an object after set that object. But I am getting type error. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'val'). How should I do that with firebase 9?

Here is the code that I want to work:

```
set(push(ref(db, "expenses")), expense)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        dispatch(
          addExpense({
            id: snapshot.key,
            ...expense,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("This failed.", e);
      });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why your code doesn't work

The documentation of [set(ref, value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#set) shows that is is defined as:

> ```
> function set(ref: DatabaseReference, value: unknown): Promise<void>
> ```

It returns a `Promise<void>`, so there's no `snapshot` being passed to your then.

If the promise resolves (and thus your `then` callback gets called) that the `expense` was written to the database on the server as is.

---

#### How to fix it

If you want to get the key of the `push` call, you can capture that outside of the `set` call already:

```
const newRef = push(ref(db, "expenses"));
set(newRef, expense)
  .then(() => {
    dispatch(
      addExpense({
        id: newRef.key,
        ...expense,
      })
    );
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("This failed.", e);
  });
```

Calling `push` is a pure client-side operation, which is synchronous, so that doesn't require `await` or `then` (which should be used with **a**synchronous operations).

---

#### Further considerations

Note though that now you're only showing the expense locally after it's been written to the server. If that is a requirement for your use-case, then . But when using Firebase it is quite common to:

1. Use a permanent, `onValue` listener on `expenses` to show the latest expenses in the UI.
2. Write the new expense with a simple call, without a `then()` listener: `set(push(ref(db, "expenses")), expense);`
3. The Firebase SDK will then immediately call the local `onValue` listener with the new value, with the assumption that the write will succeed.
4. So your UI will show the local value straight away, giving the user an almost instant response.
5. In the (more uncommon) case that the server (i.e. your security rules) rejects the write operation, the SDK calls `onValue` again with the corrected data, so your UI can update the state.